# c++ library with c interface

Tags: c++, c, linux

i need to write a library in c++ , usable by client to do some operations in a remote server. The only thing in the specific i haven't done yet it's: The c++ library need a C interface. Let me explain better:
From client using this lib i need to do call something like:
int operation(void* addr);
if int<0 error
and so..
But the library it's a class in c++.
So my answer is.. Need I a global variable holding the instance of class in the library?
The are some better option to develop this C interface of C++ class?

Thx in advice for answer.

Comment: The key answer is already downthere. Don't forget to `extern "C" {}` your interface declarations.

Comment: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/mixing-c-and-cpp.html

Comment: For a real-life example, check out the 0MQ library, http://www.zeromq.org: written in C++ with a C interface (and a C++ interface wrapped around that).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the [PIMPL idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer) in the C wrapper. You provide a method `YourClass_Create` that internally calls the constructor (using `new`) and returns the pointer to your class instance; for the client code this will be just an opaque handle (it may be a `typedef` for `void *`), to be passed to every function of your C interface to specify on which instance it has to work (just like `FILE *` in `stdio`).

All these functions will have to do is to call the corresponding method on the handle (converted back to a pointer to your class) and translate exceptions to error codes.

---

As *@jdv-Jan de Vaan* pointed out in his comment, don't forget the necessary `#ifdef`ed `extern "C" {}` around your C wrapper code, otherwise you may get linker errors.